# Address boundary error on my linked list count function in C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I'm implementing a linked list library to teach myself C. I've got most things working nicely except iteration, which is being used for the length function I've made. Here's the structs used for the list

```
typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
typedef struct List List;

struct ListNode {
    void *val;
    ListNode *next;
};

struct List {
    ListNode *head;
};
```

I've also got a couple of other functions for manipulating the list, namely a create, push and pop function. Here's the create function if it matters:

```
List *list_create(){
    List *list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    return list;
}
```

Here's the function that's having issues, though:

```
int list_length(List *list){
    ListNode *current = list->head;
    int count = 0;

    // Iterate through the list, adding to the count
    while(current != NULL){
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return count;
}
```

For some reason when it reaches the last iteration, the while predicate doesn't work and instead, I get the following error:

```
Job 1, './linked_list ' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Is there anything immediately obvious that I'm doing wrong? You can find all the (not completely working) code at https://github.com/tominated/linked_list

Comment: Make sure that whenever you create a new node in your list, initialize the ListNode* next to NULL. Edit: I see in line 93 of your code on github, you have *new_head = malloc(sizeof *new_head);. That shouldn't you want sizeof(new_head), I believe.

Comment: I actually read somewhere that it is an equivalent way to write a malloc call (it was in a style guide I was reading somewhere)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list_create` leaves `head` uninitialised.  `list_push` (in your github code) creates a new item and sets `head` to its `next` pointer.  When you iterate through the list, the last item points to this uninitialised pointer rather than to `NULL`.  From this point on, you are into undefined behaviour; the chances are high you'll quickly get a SIGSEGV.

The fix is simple - you just need to set `head` to `NULL` when you create the list.

```
List *list_create(){
    List *list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    if (list != NULL) {
        list->head = NULL;
    }
    return list;
}
```